# Select image and create object. Processing 2.0

Tags: image, oop, processing, draw

here is a code snippet from my Image class:

```
class Image{

  public int width;
  public int height;

  public PImage img;

  Image(PApplet parent){

    width = 512;
    height = 512;

    img = new PImage();
    img = parent.loadImage("test.jpg");
    img.resize(width, height);
  }
}
```

I draw it in the main file in such a way:

```
image(image.img, 287, 280);
```

I'd like to choose the image having clicked it:

```
void mousePressed() {
   if (gui.btnOver1) {
     selectInput("Choose file:", "fileSelected");
   }
}
```

However, I don't know how to use this function in an OOP way:

```
void fileSelected(File selection) {
  if (selection == null) {
    println("Window was closed or the user hit cancel.");
  } else {
    img = loadImage(selection.getAbsolutePath());
    img.loadPixels();
  }
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking. What exactly do you mean by "use this function in an OOP way"?

Answer (score -1):

what about adding a method to your class like:

```
class Image{

  public int width;
  public int height;

  public PImage img;

  Image(PApplet parent){

      width = 512;
      height = 512;

     img = new PImage();
     img = parent.loadImage("test.jpg");
     img.resize(width, height);
  }

   public void loadNew(path){
      img = loadImage(path);
     // I don't think you need to .updatePixels() after .loadImage()
   }
}
```

Then you use it like that:

```
void fileSelected(File selection) {
  if (selection == null) {
    println("Window was closed or the user hit cancel.");
  } else {
     // assuming you have an 'image' object of the type Image
     image.loadNew(selection.getAbsolutePath());
  }
}
```

Note: 
*It's been a while since I wrote my last line of Processing code and it may be a bit wrong, but it should answer your question*

You could even have a function to draw the Image object, rather than calling the property `img`of your `image`, 
like that:

```
// a method of your class
public void draw(int x, int y){
  image(img, x, y);
}
```

and then inside the main `draw()` you will call

```
// always your image object here
image.draw(20, 34);
```

I hope it helps!